# overriding already overridden classes with a module - Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I KNOW THIS QUESTION IS NOT SPECIFICALLY TIED TO PROGRAMMING. BUT I REALLY WANT TO UNDERSTAND PRESTASHOP'S BEHAVIOUR OF OVERRIDING FILES VIA MODULES.

I want to extend a MYSQL table, let's say, `Orders`. A raw sql query in Module's install method would get this, no problem. But I wanna add this column to `Order` Model as well, which is where the main problem would come. Since I must override it like this:

```
  public function __construct($id = null, $id_lang = null)
  {
    parent::__construct($id, $id_lang);
    self::$definition['fields']['new_column'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING);
  }
```

My question is, how do I make sure that if `override` directory already has an `Order.php` with a `__construct`, how do I make it to merge changes rather than throwing error.. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prestashop doesn't encourage using of overrides within modules at all. Because how I know there is no way to merge two overrides and only the last one will work if you will find a way to install a module with the second override. So they recommend extending existing classes and add all necessary data from there. For example, in your case, it should be something like this

```
class Order extends OrderCore
{
    public $new_filed;

    public function __construct($id = null, $id_lang = null)
    {
        Order::$definition['fields']['new_column'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING);
        parent::__construct($id, $id_lang);
    }
}
```

and just include this class file inside your module. So if something similar will be included within another module no conflict should appear except if the properties will have the same name.

Comment: let's say, a store developer already created this class override with __construct method in it, would Prestashop allow my module to install if my module also registers an override of a same class and method...??

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that problem will be similar like with overrides in this case and the only differences are that you will be allowed to install module but us the result you will get a fatal error about a class redeclaration and also any files will not be rewritten in the overrides folder

Comment: so in conclusion, we should generally avoid using overrides as much as we can...?